# Javascript void. How to work?

Tags: javascript

When I am using  to fetch header.html from other folder then drop down menu is not working. But when i am putting the same code of header.html in my working file then my drop-down menu works. so is it happening because of javascript:void(0) ? Or any other solution on this?

My code is

Menu

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3

About

- P1
- P2
- P3

Comment: `javascript:void(0)` is a mixture of bad practises.

Answer (score 0):

it will not work.

for example, if you use the following code,

```
 var div=document.getElementById('div');
```

then that div element must be available. So the above line will work only on the same file where the element exists not outside.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you are using this but in any case it's not pretty to use inline Javascript.  You can achieve the same result by calling [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) - in plain old *JS* (and pretty much every framework out there) the native event will be passed as a parameter to your listener's callback, ***e.g.***

```html
<a id="foo" href="/">null link</a>
```

```js
var a = document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E5V46/1/)